# how to resolve segment:offset address in GDB

Tags: memory-management, gdb

```
(gdb) info registers ds
   ds             0x7b  123
(gdb) disassemble
   Dump of assembler code for function printf@plt:
   0x0804831c <+0>: jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x804a008
=> 0x08048322 <+6>: push   0x10
   0x08048327 <+11>:    jmp    0x80482ec
End of assembler dump.
```

Can someone describe me how to map ds:0x804a008 address into linear address? I can use "x/xw address" command? If it is not clear I'd like to know where to this first jmp function in code jumps.

Comment: Is this for a platform that doesn't use a flat address space?

Comment: `ds:` is the default data segment, it is used when no other segment register is indicated in the instruction. While an offset could be set for the segment, all x86 architectures leave it at zero, so you can disregard the segment prefix.

Answer (score 1):

`0x804a008` is an address in the processes linear address space - the DWORD in that memory location is the address that will be jumped to (ie., `0x804a008` is a pointer).
`

So

```
x/xw 0x804a008
```

will dump the contents of the pointer, and

```
disasm *0x804a008
```

will disassemble the code that jumping through that pointer will execute.

Comment: (gdb) x/xw 0x804a008
0x804a008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+20>: 0x08048322

Comment: @user480162: Have a read of the article at http://www.thexploit.com/sploitdev/how-is-glibc-loaded-at-runtime/ to get an idea of what's going on here.  Basically the first time through, it executes the code at `0x08048322` which resolves the actual location of `printf()` and puts it into the pointer.  So next time it's called it'll just jump right to `printf()`

Comment: This only answers the question if the base address of the ds segment is 0x0. For modern operating systems this is the case, but if someone is trying to get an address at an offset to a TLS segment like gs or fs, where the base is arbitrary, this answer does not help.

Answer (score -3):

Modern x86 OS don't use segmented addressing. Real mode segmented address can only represent 1Mb of address space. This addressing scheme is only used during the boot process for compatibility reasons.

The OS set all the segment registers to a *selector* that represent the flat 32-bit address space of your process but you shouldn't have to worry about that.

ds:0x804a008 is just the same as 0x804a008

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Modern x86 OS do use segments for thread local storage. While the actual value of the segment registers themselves aren't actually relevant in 64 bit mode, use of the FS or GS prefix opcode causes the CPU to add the FSBASE or GSBASE MSR value to the linear address.