# How to use a logical address with an FS or GS base in gdb?

Tags: gdb, x86, memory-segmentation

gdb provides functionality to read or write to a specific *linear address*, for example:

```
(gdb) x/1wx 0x080483e4
0x80483e4 <main>:       0x83e58955
(gdb)
```

but how do you specify a logical address ? I came accross the following instruction:

```
   0x0804841a <+6>:     mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
```

how can i read the memory at "%gs:0x14" in gdb, or translate this logical address to a linear address that i could use in `x` command ?

note: i know that i could simply read %eax after this instruction, but that is not my concern

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve segment:offset adres in GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006686/how-to-resolve-segmentoffset-adres-in-gdb). That doesn't have a good answer though.

Comment: Arguably a better answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617004/148439 that covers obtaining the base address of the TLS segment behind `%gs:` or `%fs:` (depending on arch) but seemingly not possible in GDB directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how can i read the memory at "%gs:0x14" in gdb

You can't: there is no way for GDB to know how the segment to which `%gs` refers to has been set up.

> or translate this logical address to a linear address that i could use in x command

Again, you can't do this in general. However, you appear to be on 32-bit x86 Linux, and there you *can* do that -- the `%gs` is set up to point to the thread descriptor via `set_thread_area` system call.

You can do `catch syscall set_thread_area` in GDB, and examine the parameters (each thread will have one such call). The code to actually do that is [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/nptl/sysdeps/i386/tls.h#l230). Once you know how `%gs` has been set up, just add 0x14 to the `base_addr`, and you are done.

Comment: Nice answer. Unfortunately, my program seems to not call set_thread_area(2). You can see the source code here: http://pastebin.com/us5sbzVg (compilation options provided in source code).

Comment: @user368507 Your program only has one thread. The program *does* call `set_thread_area` (you should be able to see that under `strace`). I was able to catch that call with GDB; not sure why you claim that `set_thread_area` is not called.

Comment: my mistake. I used another computer after the OP. It was an x86-64... You're anwser works perfectly well on 32bit x86. I guess things are different on x86-64.

Comment: @user368507 "I guess things are different on x86-64" -- indeed they are. There is no `set_thread_area` system call on `x86_64`, and it doesn't use `%gs` to access thread locals.

Comment: I don't buy "there is no way for GDB to know how the segment to which `%gs` refers to has been set up". GDB is running in user mode and can't read the GDT/LDT, but it could write machine code for something like `mov %gs:0x14,%eax` into some memory it controls and then jump to it. In that way, it could "read" `%gs:0x14`.

Comment: @AlexD: Or under Linux, could just ask the kernel what the GS base is with `arch_prctl(ARCH_GET_GS)` in the context of the target process.  (BTW, modern OSes don't use the GDT/LDT to set FS/GS base, they use the MSRs or even new instructions like `wrfsbase` on CPUs where available).  IDK if ptrace has a way for the debugger to just directly query the FS/GS bases; I thought I remembered something about GDB being able to query it somehow but it's not part of `info reg all`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Apparently, `info reg all` doesn't list all registers. The command `maintenance print register-groups` shows which register groups each register belongs to. For me, `fs_base` and `gs_base` belong to the `system` group (as well as `save` and `restore`, but not `all`), so `info reg system` (or `i r sy`) prints them.

Answer (score 6):

As answered in [Using GDB to read MSRs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095665/using-gdb-to-read-msrs), this is possible with gdb 8, using the registers `$fs_base` and `$gs_base`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is to read the content of EAX register as you can see the value of %gs:0x14 is moved to EAX.

In GDB, set a breakpoint at the address right after 0x0804841a with break. For example

```
break *0x0804841e
```

Then run the program and you can print the contents of EAX register with

```
info registers eax
```

Comment: Yes, but the question already mentions this method: *note: i know that i could simply read %eax after this instruction, but that is not my concern*.  Some code does things like `sub %gs:0x14, %eax` / jnz, not loading it into a separate register first.  (e.g. GCC's `-fstack-protector-strong` will do that to check the stack cookie.)