# How to print segment:offset addresses with GDB?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I am running POK, which in turn is running RTEMS inside a partition.
The system makes active use of x86 segments and I can't find out how I can tell GDB to consider this.

If I execute the following inline asm code, the EIP (see comment) will be in the right location. When I load the right SS (0x23) and check this location with gdb it will show me 0x00000000. If I load it back into EAX and check EAX with 'info reg' it will show me the right EIP address.

```
"movl 56(%1), %%ebx          \t\n" //move user esp address to register

"movl 60(%1), %%eax          \t\n"
"movl %%eax , %%gs           \t\n" // move user's SS to gs register

"movl 44(%1), %%eax          \t\n" //move eip to register
"movl %%eax , %%gs:(%%ebx)   \t\n" // move eip to user esp
```

%GS is the offset into the GDT, so I tried to find the GDT and then reconstruct the base address of the memory segment myself, but GDB wasn't of help there, too.

If I omitt %%gs: and let GDB print the memory referenced by %%ebx it will show the value moved there, but the programm isn't finding it in it's memory.

Is there a way to find out the right segment (base address) with GDB?
Is GDB even capable of handling segmentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006686/how-to-resolve-segmentoffset-adres-in-gdb || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354063/how-to-use-a-logical-address-in-gdb